# Flutter: Twilio programmable video cannot get the correct participant Network Quality Level

Tags: flutter, twilio

I am using the **twilio_programmable_video** package, been trying to get the Network quality level but I always get an "UNKNOWN" value, here is my connection option.

```
connectOptions = ConnectOptions(
    token,
    roomName: name,
    preferredAudioCodecs: [OpusCodec()],
    audioTracks: [LocalAudioTrack(true, 'audio_track-$trackId')],
    dataTracks: [
      LocalDataTrack(
        DataTrackOptions(name: 'data_track-$trackId'),
      )
    ],
    videoTracks: [LocalVideoTrack(true, _cameraCapturer)],
    networkQualityConfiguration: NetworkQualityConfiguration(
      local: NetworkQualityVerbosity.NETWORK_QUALITY_VERBOSITY_MINIMAL,
      remote: NetworkQualityVerbosity.NETWORK_QUALITY_VERBOSITY_MINIMAL,
    ),
    enableNetworkQuality: true,
    enableDominantSpeaker: true,
  );
```

how I access the participant Network quality level

```
participant.networkQualityLevel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out

for the localParticipant I listen to this event (call this onConnectedEvent)

```
_streamSubscriptions.add(
    _room.localParticipant!.onNetworkQualityLevelChanged.listen((event) =>
        localParticipantNetworkLevel(event.networkQualityLevel)));


localParticipantNetworkLevel(NetworkQualityLevel level) {
   print("LOCAL PARTICIPANT NETWORK LEVEL =======>  $level");
}
```

- Remote participant ( trigger this inside the **onParticipantConnected** event)

  ```
    _streamSubscriptions.add( event.remoteParticipant.onNetworkQualityLevelChanged.listen((event) => remoteParticipantNetworkLeve(event.networkQualityLevel)));
    remoteParticipantNetworkLeve(NetworkQualityLevel level) {
    print("REMOTE LEVEL $level");
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can log `room.localParticipant.networkQualityLevel`.

If you are using this in Group Rooms, the Network API only works in Group rooms, not P2P. If you grep the repo you'll probably be able to determine the logic stating why we see it "unknown".

These may also be helpful!
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/519 or you might be seeing something closer to https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/issues/1679.

Let me know if this helps at all!